# How can I cancel a job returned by `launch` in another function in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I've got a little demo app that records audio continuously in a coroutine launched from a composable.  The button element looks like this

```
Button(onClick = {
            if (audioPermissionState.status.isGranted) {
                if (!listener.isListening()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Audio permission granted")
                    listener.listen()
                    val job = composableScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                        listener.read()
                        Log.d(TAG, "Listener is reading")
                    }
                } else {
                    job.cancel()
                    listener.stop()
                }
            } else {
                audioPermissionState.launchPermissionRequest()
            }
        }) {
            Text(stringResource(R.string.start_listening))
        }
```

The `listener` object is a Kotlin class initialized in the composable that include `Button`, and it works fine.  If the `listener` is not listening, then when the button is pressed it begins listening, and starts a coroutine off the main thread that continuously reads from an `AudioRecord`.  When the button is clicked again I would like to cancel the job and stop `AudioRecord` object from recording.

I tried declaring the `job` variable in the composable above `Button` as mutable state, but cannot do so without initializing which I can't seem to do.  How can I access the `job` variable in the other branch of my if/else statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run this by declaring a null job at top of composable as mutable state

```
var job: Job by remember { mutableStateOf(Job(null)) }
```

This seems like an ugly hack though.